# Display only the first product from an order in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, woocommerce, break

In Woocommerce, I'm using the code below to get the products in the order:

```
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

   $product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $order->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );

    $is_visible        = $product && $product->is_visible();
    $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_permalink', $is_visible ? $product->get_permalink( $item ) : '', $item, $order );

    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $product_permalink ? sprintf( '<p><a href="%s">%s</a>', $product_permalink, $item['name'] ) : $item['name'], $item, $is_visible );
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity_html', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times; %s', $item['qty'] ) . '</strong></p>', $item );
    echo $product->get_image();
}
```

but I need to get only the first product not all of them. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add [`break;`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) at the end of the foreach loop, to **display only the first item**:

```
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

   $product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $order->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );

    $is_visible        = $product && $product->is_visible();
    $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_permalink', $is_visible ? $product->get_permalink( $item ) : '', $item, $order );

    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $product_permalink ? sprintf( '<p><a href="%s">%s</a>', $product_permalink, $item['name'] ) : $item['name'], $item, $is_visible );
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity_html', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times; %s', $item['qty'] ) . '</strong></p>', $item );
    echo $product->get_image();

    break; // <=== We stop the loop
}
```

---

To display all items but excluding the first one you can use a **counter** for example, like:

```
$counter = 0; // Initialize the counter

foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    $counter++; // Increase the count

    if( $counter !== 1 ){
        $product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $order->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );

        $is_visible = $product && $product->is_visible();
        $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_permalink', $is_visible ? $product->get_permalink( $item ) : '', $item, $order );

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $product_permalink ? sprintf( '<p><a href="%s">%s</a>', $product_permalink, $item['name'] ) : $item['name'], $item, $is_visible );
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity_html', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times; %s', $item['qty'] ) . '</strong></p>', $item );
        echo $product->get_image();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok , If I want to view all but the first product ?

Comment: @GamalElwazeery Added an addition for it…